# Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing a problem in datagridview. I have done some code in keydown event for changing the tab focus but when tab reaches last of column it gives a error

> "Current cell cannot be set to an invisible cell".

I have made last of cell is invisible because i don't want to be visible that cell.

I have written following code in KeyDown event

```
private void m3dgvDepositDetails_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && notlastColumn)
    {
      e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
      int iColumn = m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
      int iRow = m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
      if (iColumn == m3dgvDepositDetails.Columns.Count - 1)
        m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell = m3dgvDepositDetails[0, iRow + 1];
      else
        m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell = m3dgvDepositDetails[iColumn + 1, iRow];
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
    cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any hidden columns in your grid after last visible column?

Comment: I have made last of cell is invisible because i don't want to be visible that cell.

Comment: so you should use `if (iColumn >= m3dgvDepositDetails.Columns.Count - 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is quite self-explanatory: you are setting the `CurrentCell` as an invisible cell and it is prohibited, that means that the cell's row **or** the cell's column is hidden. To avoid this don't hide rows/columns or check the `Visible` property before setting the `CurrentCell`.

If the problem is the last column you should use:

```
private void m3dgvDepositDetails_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && notlastColumn)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                int iColumn = m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
                int iRow = m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                if (iColumn >= m3dgvDepositDetails.Columns.Count - 2)
                    m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell = m3dgvDepositDetails[0, iRow + 1];
                else
                    m3dgvDepositDetails.CurrentCell = m3dgvDepositDetails[iColumn + 1, iRow];

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CusException cex = new CusException(ex);
            cex.Show(MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when you try to select an hidden cell. Also you should not set rows to invisible in a datagridview since it has bugs.

One solution would be instead of setting the row invisible, just filter the data source and get only those records which you want. This will be slow but can be served as a workaround.

**OR**

You can try using following (Not tested)

```
cm.SuspendBinding();
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Visible = false; // Set your datatgridview invisible here
cm.ResumeBinding();
```